# Moving an application from SQLite to Oracle DB

Tags: .net, oracle, sqlite, oracle11g, berkeley-db

I have a .Net application which has a SQLite database. I want to switch my database to Oracle Berkeley DB. What are the steps to move the application from SQLite to Oracle Berkeley DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL interface of Oracle Berkeley DB is compatible with SQLite, so most likely you do not need to modify the SQL statements used in your application.

1. Download ADO.NET package for Berkeley DB, from
   http://download.oracle.com/otn/berkeley-db/dbsql-adodotnet-6.2.23.zip
2. Take a look at the docs:
   http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17076_05/html/bdb-sql/buildinstall.html#ado_net
   , follow the instructions to build the ADO.NET provider for Berkeley
   DB